# ORA-01017 Invalid Username/Password when connecting from SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've created the user using (in sqlplus running `sqlplus / as sysdba`):

```
create user foo identified by bar;
grant connect to foo;
```

and I can't connect to the user using SQL Developer. I've try upper case and lowercase password with no success.

I can connect from sqlplus using:

```
conn foo/bar
```

I've installed oracle few times but I have in sql developer different user that I'm connecting to and I can select from same tables in sqlplus so both sql developer and sqlplus use same database.

Comment: Basic or TNS connection? Have you tried both?

Comment: I've tested using Basic

Comment: can you connect from sqlplus?

Comment: Yes, I can connect from sqlplus.

Comment: @jcubic: Have you tried to alter the password afterwards `ALTER USER foo IDENTIFIED BY bar;`?

Comment: @vercelli yes I've tried that.

Comment: @jcubic Have you tried on cmd `sqlplus foo/bar@servername:port/dbsid` ?

Comment: @vercelli I've got the same eror ORA-01017.

Comment: @jcubic: Ok! That's good... I think ;)

Comment: @jcubic: I really think you may be connecting to different databases. Try selecting `v$instance and v$database`

Comment: `select count(*) from v$instance;` show one instance.

Comment: @jcubic: `select instance_name from v$instance; select name from v$database;`

Comment: @jcubic Are those the expected values?

Comment: Is this the same as sid in sql developer?

Comment: @jcubic: you probably should use orcl2 as SID in sqldeveloper

Comment: When I use orcl2 I've got error : `ORA-12505: TNS: listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor`

Comment: What is your ORACLE_SID when you connect through SQL\*Plus? Is TWO_TASK or LOCAL set? What do vercelli's queries show you when you're connected through SQL\*Plus and SQL Developer? What does `show parameters service_names` show in both? Are you sure you're connecting to the same host with both? Etc. You're hitting two databases, the issue is proving it... *8-)

Comment: What about `lsnrctl status` ?

Comment: I have two instances the other was using different port 1522 I've connected using orcl2 sid, thanks for your help.

Comment: @jcubic: Glad it helped!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43995838/6067272 This works for me by checking use OCI/Thick driver.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify. The problem was that there were two databases running on the same server on different ports. The user did not exist in one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you had another user which can connected to Oracle from SQL Developer, you can just simple duplicate that connection, edit its credential and reconnect.
Moreover, you can should use sqlplus to connect to Oracle Server (remember to check ORACLE_SID before connect).
If everything is ok, then it'll work well on SQL Developer.